# React design pattern for fetching items

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a number of React components that need to fetch certain items to display. The components could be functional components, except for a very simple `componentDidMount` callback. Is there a good design pattern that would allow me to return to functional components?

```
class Things extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchThings()
  }

  render() {
    things = this.props.things
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using react-redux and I'm also using `connect` to connect my component to my reducers and actions. Here's that file:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Things from './things'
import { fetchThings } from '../../actions/thing_actions'

const mapStateToProps = ({ things }) => ({
  things: things,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  fetchThings: () => fetchThings()
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Things)
```

Would it make sense to fetch the things in this file instead? Maybe something like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Things from './things'
import { fetchThings } from '../../actions/thing_actions'

const mapStateToProps = ({ things }) => ({
  things: things,
})

class ThingsContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchThings()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Things things={this.props.things} />
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ThingsContainer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components are meant to be components that don't *do* **anything**. You just give them props and they render. In fact, if your component needs to fetch anything at all, it's likely your component should be transformed into a [*container*](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) which fetches the data you need. You can then abstract the UI part of your component into one or more pure functional components which your container renders by passing the data it got as props.

I believe the presentational/container component split is the pattern you're looking for here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of the container design pattern, but it seems like overkill because `fetchThings` is literally the only thing the component does.

But this gave me an idea. What if I use the "`connect`" file I already have to give the component props to also fetch the things? I edited my question with this idea.

Comment: That would be making your component _both_ presentational and connected, which is generally frowned upon when it comes to larger components, but is OK for small components.

Comment: Really? Why is that frowned upon? I generally see the strength of redux that it allows you to use more functional components by using connect to supply them with props directly from your reducers.

Comment: Because you should try to separate presentation from logic whenever possible. Presentation and logic together in a single component can become very complex very fast without the programmer noticing.